# 1D Wave equation with mixed boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The 1D wave equation:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
u_{tt}(x,t)-c^2u_{xx}(x,t)=0\\
u_{x}(0,t)=0 \\
u(\pi,t)=Dcos(\Omega t)\\
u(x,0) = 0\\
u_{t}(x,0)=0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

I understand that the first step is to homogenize the boundary conditions such that the new problem becomes:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
v_{tt}(x,t)-c^2u_{xx}(x,t)=f(x,t)\\
v_{x}(0,t)=0\\
v(\pi,t)=0 \\
v(x,0) = g(x)\\
v_{t}(x,0) = 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Which leads to an inhomogeneous wave equation. But getting there is what I need help with. I assume that $v(x,t)$ must fulfill the following but I have trouble with finding an appropriate $\tilde u(x,t)$ to subtract the boundary conditions due to the x-derivative:
$$
v(x,t) = u(x,t) - \tilde u(x,t) \\
v(\pi,t) = u(\pi,t) - \tilde u(\pi,t) = 0 \\
v_{x}(0, t) = u_{x}(0,t) - \tilde u_{x}(0,t) = 0
$$

Best regards

Comment: Try to find the $\bar u$ in the following form $\bar u = u + A(t)x + B(t)$

Comment: Thank you for your input! When trying that I simply obtain A(t) = 0 and B(t) = 0...

Comment: Oh, sorry. $\bar u = A(t)x + B(t)$

Comment: $\bar{u}=D\cos(\Omega t)$ does the job.

Comment: Sorry for late replay but thank you very much! It does indeed.